# netflix in firefox 53 and ubuntu 16.04. one machine works, one doesn't

Tags: netflix

I have two computers, both with clean installs of 64-bit Ubuntu 16.04 and all updates.  both have Firefox 53.  Netflix runs fine on one but on the other, I get a F7701-1003 error and no video.  I have tried disabling add-ons in Firefox.  No joy.  I'm an experienced PC user, but relatively new to  Ubuntu.  Any help appreciated.  I hope Sling TV writes an Ubuntu compatible app, too.

Comment: Did you try [netflix help](https://help.netflix.com/en/node/32661)?

Answer (score 3):

Check the DRM setting in the Firefox preferences.

[image]

Clear these caches in the Firefox preferences.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This solution worked for me on Xenial (as posted [here on bugzilla.mozilla.org](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1353851) ):

> "...the problem is that with the latest update the setting **media.eme.enabled** reverted to "false". Firefox 55 also shows this as a default setting on my desktop PC, meaning that if this isn't just that way on my PC anyone who would want to use it would need to dig into about:config first. Is this intentional?
>
> Anyway, changing that setting to "true" makes it work again."

Answer (score 0):

I find Netflix on Firefox dicy because of the user agent string -- claims that is doesn't matter anymore are false (for me at least).  The default does not work.  An earlier one I set up stopped working after a few weeks.  The latest one which works is:

```
Linux / Chrome 53: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/535.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/53.0.2785.34 Safari/537.36
```

Get the User Agent Switcher plugin, and add a user agent string called "Netflix watcher" with the above definition.  Set it from the Tools menu.